# PNG images not loaded

Tags: html, image, png, src

I am the developer of www.zundelcristea.com website.

For some reason, [png images are not being loaded](http://www.zundelcristea.com/wp-content/themes/azc/library/images/mobile-menu-icon.png), although they do exist on the right path, with the right permissions (664, as any other file on the server).

My `.htaccess` doesn't contain anything related to images, nor their folders.
I have no idea what else I can check.

Locally, .png are loaded normally.
Any suggestion is much appreciated

[**EDIT**]
Nothing in error_log

Comment: Check error log of your httpd server

Comment: Thanks. 

Nothing in error_log, but nothing in access_log either. That is strange. Why wouldn't I have a trace of .png page access in access_log?

Comment: This is odd, because you should have at least one entry in either log - check your httpd settings and fix logging first - doe sit log i.e. page requests or anything else? do you have anything that can i.e. reroute PNG requests elsewhere (cache/etc) so no request to the server you expect? and finally, it starts looking like off-topic question here :)

Comment: My bad, access_log was just slow on being updated by the server. 
It takes about 1min to be updated by alwaysdata. 

No cache system, nothing in .htaccess. 

I can't think of anything rerouting .png requests really

Comment: Maybe you FTP'd them in text mode instead of binary and they were corrupted by extra LFCR characters.

Comment: 1 mins to sync logs? unless I miss something this is very odd

Comment: Many thanks. I'll read about this but I tested out by reuploading them in binary|auto mode using FileZilla and this works. If you guys would make this an answer, so that I can mark this as answered. 

Thanks a lot, you are ending up hours of roaming around the web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You transferred them in text mode:

```
$ pngcheck -v mobile-menu-icon.png
  File: mobile-menu-icon.png (425 bytes)
  File is CORRUPTED. It seems to have suffered DOS->Unix conversion.
  ERRORS DETECTED in mobile-menu-icon.png
```

The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following values:

```
(decimal)              137  80  78  71  13  10  26  10
(hexadecimal)           89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a
(ASCII C notation)    \211   P   N   G  \r  \n \032 \n
```

From the PNG specification, "rationale": This signature both identifies the file as a PNG file and provides for immediate detection of common file-transfer problems. The first two bytes distinguish PNG files on systems that expect the first two bytes to identify the file type uniquely. The first byte is chosen as a non-ASCII value to reduce the probability that a text file may be misrecognized as a PNG file; also, it catches bad file transfers that clear bit 7. Bytes two through four name the format. The CR-LF sequence catches bad file transfers that alter newline sequences. The control-Z character stops file display under MS-DOS. The final line feed checks for the inverse of the CR-LF translation problem.

See http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/